# Problems with Google Maps API v3 markers event + jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3, tabs

i have a html page with tabs (jquery ui tabs).

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-0"><wp:i18n key="MAP" /></a></li> 
        <li><a href="#tabs-1"><wp:i18n key="ABSTRACT" /></a></li> 
        <li><a href="#tabs-2"><wp:i18n key="PARTNERSHIP" /></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-0">   
        <%@include file="inc_tabs/project_map.jsp" %>
    </div>        
    <div id="tabs-1">   
        <%@include file="inc_tabs/project_abstract.jsp" %>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <%@include file="inc_tabs/project_contacts.jsp" %>
    </div>

</div>
```

In the first tab i have a google map with some markers. I have to add a click event to marker to change the selected tab. On click i want to change to tab 2.

here is my code:

```
    var marker5= new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(44.451681,8.755302)
    }); 

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker5, 'click', function() {
        window.location.href='<wp:url page="projectdetails"><wp:urlPar name="projectId" ><c:out value="${project.id}" />#tabs-2</wp:urlPar></wp:url>';
    });
```

on clicking the page is reloaded and the url in the browser is changed from

```
http://localhost:8080/ENPIM/en/projectdetails.page?projectId=63963
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/ENPIM/en/projectdetails.page?projectId=63963#tabs-2
```

but the tab is not selected...

Can anyone help me?

thanks

andrea

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will only observe clicks inside #tabs. Changing the URL doesn't have an effect to `$.tabs()`

Trigger the click-event for the particular link:

```
$('a[href="#tabs-2"]','#tabs' ).click();
```

Comment: i solved using  `google.maps.event.addListener(marker<c:out value="${mis.regionId}"/>, 'click', function() {  $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 2 ); });`